# return string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get apiUrl depending on a user's input

```
<form name="test">
  <input type="text" name="Edit">
  <input type="button" value="Test" onClick="gettext()">
  <input type="text" name="Edit2" readonly style="border:1px solid white">
</form>
```

Then i have a script which does not work, to form a url based on that

```
<script>

function gettext(Edit, Edit2) {
 document.test.Edit2.value=document.test.Edit.value;};

var apiKey = '07gh4c95ca7e23d41ghggf/';
var userWord = Edit2;
var txtjson = '/json';
var apiUrl = 'http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/' + apiKey + userWord + txtjson;

</script>
```

I need var userWord to be a string to insert its value in the apiUrl.

Please help me with that. Thank you

Comment: And you have tried to google haven't you?

Comment: Make `userWord` a function that returns the value of your input and invoke it when you create your url.

Comment: [Unrelated] Note `document.test.Edit2` is a non standard way to access the field, better use  `document.forms.test.elements.Edit2`.

Comment: Why does your `gettext` function have paramters (that you don't use)? Why is the construction of the `apiUrl` outside of that click handler function? Why is nothing done with `apiUrl` after it has been constructed (you need to output it)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit2 is not declared outside the gettext function. Try this:

```
function gettext(Edit, Edit2) {
    document.test.Edit2.value = document.test.Edit.value;
    return document.test.Edit2.value;
}

var userWord = gettext(<param1>, <param2>);
```

Comment: What are these `param1`/`param2` doing there?

Comment: That would be the parameters that you use when you call the gettext function. I would say 'Edit' and 'Edit2', and don't forget to add those as id's to the input text fields

Comment: It might be clearer to use angle brackets `< >` to denote placeholder values - using square brackets makes them look like arrays.

Comment: @Ronald01990: No. Because those parameters are not used in the function at all, there's no reason to pass any arguments.